# IIS7 (Windows) Authentication -- Cannot figure out why new website errors 401

Tags: authentication, iis

I am trying to make a new website on an IIS server, of which has websites that are using Windows Authentication just fine.  However, for the life of me, I cannot figure out why my new website refuses access (401.2)

Basically, I create a new website and add a single .html file ("Hello, World").  I can access it just fine.  But turn off Anonymous, leaving on Windows Authentication, I get prompted for ID/PWD, ending always a 401.2

So, I decided to make a new website as a copy of the existing working website on the same webserver.  I've even gone and made the new website share the same App Pool and the same Physical Path.  This way, as far as I can tell, the only possible differences between the two websites is now the IIS configuration of the two sites.  Still can't authenticate.

I've switched the bindings, doesn't help.

I've even compared the settings in applicationHost.config, making sure they're equal.

Any ideas?  Thanks in advance.

Comment: 401.2 means client and server failed to negotiate an authentication protocol.

Comment: Summary so far:  Have a working website, trying to make a copy of it.  Copy won't authenticate user.  Copy is using same Application pool as original, same working (web) folder as the original.  I copied all settings in applicationHost.config for original website over to copy.  Even switched bindings.  I still cannot get the copy website to authenticate me.  What else could possibly be still different?

Answer (score 4):

I've used this article several times for problems like these with some success: http://blogs.msdn.com/b/david.wang/archive/2005/07/14/howto-diagnose-iis-401-access-denied.aspx  Hope it helps!

Comment: I looked at your page, and it indicates 401.2 basically means that the client and server failed to negotiate an authentication protocol.  This isn't making sense to me, since I basically copied a working site on the same IIS server.  I tell it to use all 3 providers (Negotiate, Negotiate:Kerberos, NTLM), but it won't work on the webserver copy?

Answer (score 2):

I was advised to try running `iisreset` from the command line.  This turns out to be what I needed all along.  Seems some configuration changes do not get applied properly, even when restarting the particular website, until IIS itself is restarted.

Comment: Yeah... 2 hours of debugging, checking authentication, security, IIS logs, server logs... and an iisreset does the trick. FML